# Несколько областей безопасности в Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

В проекте с Java 7  и Spring 3.1 есть несколько областей авторизации: одна для проверки логина и пароля, а также уровня доступа к тем или иным функциям. Вторая для API адресов, на которые накручивается базовая аутентификация.

```
    public class TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    private boolean anonymous;
    private UserInfo.UserType userType;
    private UserInfo.UserLanguage userLanguage;
    private String userName = "";
    private JSONObject jsonAuthorities;
    private Long userId;
    private Long selectedOrganizationId;
    private Collection<OrganizationViewBean> organizations = new ArrayList<>();

    public TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Long currentOrganizationId, UserInfo.UserLanguage userLanguage) {
        super(null, null);
        anonymous = true;
        this.selectedOrganizationId = currentOrganizationId;
        this.userLanguage = userLanguage;
    }

    public TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Long userId,
                                                 Object principal,
                                                 String userName,
                                                 UserInfo.UserType userType,
                                                 UserInfo.UserLanguage userLanguage,
                                                 Object credentials,
                                                 Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities,
                                                 Collection<OrganizationViewBean> organizations,
                                                 Long currentOrganizationId) {
        super(principal, credentials, authorities);
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userType = userType;
        this.userLanguage = userLanguage;
        jsonAuthorities = new JSONObject();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
            jsonAuthorities.put(authority.getAuthority(), Boolean.TRUE);

        }

        for (final OrganizationViewBean organization : organizations) {
            if (organization.getRemoved() == null || !organization.getRemoved()) {
                this.organizations.add(organization);
            }
        }

        this.selectedOrganizationId = currentOrganizationId;
    }

CustomSessionAuthenticationStrategy

    public class CustomSessionAuthenticationStrategy extends ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy {
    /**
     * @param sessionRegistry the session registry which should be updated when the authenticated session is changed.
     */
    public CustomSessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
        super(sessionRegistry);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSessionChange(String originalSessionId, HttpSession newSession, Authentication auth) {
        super.onSessionChange(originalSessionId, newSession, auth);
        SessionsInfo sessionsInfo = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(newSession.getServletContext()).getBean(SessionsInfo.class);
        sessionsInfo.replaceSessionId(originalSessionId, newSession.getId());
    }
}
```

XMl-конфигурация:

```
     <context:component-scan base-package="ru.data"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.web"/>

    <security:user-service id="apiUserDetailsService">
        <security:user name="user" password="root" authorities="ADMIN" />
    </security:user-service>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="apiUserDetailsService"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="basicAuthEntryPoint" pattern="/api/**" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/*.htm" access="hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="basicAuthEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="REST Realm" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="basicAuthEntryPoint" />
    </bean>
<bean id="customExpressionHandler" class="ru.berkana.crm.security.CustomWebExpressionHandler">

    </bean>

    <bean id="customMethodExpressionHandler" class="ru.berkana.crm.security.CustomMethodExpressionHandler">

    </bean>

    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <security:expression-handler ref="customMethodExpressionHandler"/>
    </security:global-method-security>

    <security:http use-expressions="true" create-session="always">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticatedIfRequired()"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index.htm" username-parameter="login" always-use-default-target="true"
                             password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-url="/login"/>
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout.htm"/>
        <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="customAuthenticationStrategy"/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationStrategy" class="ru.security.CustomSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionRegistry"
          class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <bean id="customAuthProvider" class="ru.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider">

    </bean>
```

Проблема в том, что эти две области конфликтуют друг с другом. После базовой аутентификации получаю ошибку. Только начинаю работать с spring, поэтому буду рада любым советам

> http-apr-8080-exec-8 01/16/2021 10:18:25 ERROR [AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver] - Invoking request method resulted in exception : public java.lang.Object ru.CommonController.handleException(java.lang.Exception,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to ru.security.TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Update: похоже, причина в этом методе:

```
public static TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getCurrentUserInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken principal = ((TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal());
    if (principal == null){
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        principal = (TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) session.getAttribute("currentAnonymous");
        if (principal == null){
            SettingsInfo settingsInfo = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(request.getSession().getServletContext()).getBean(SettingsInfo.class);
            principal = new TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(settingsInfo.getCurrentOrganizationId(), settingsInfo.getCurrentLanguage());
            principal.setOrganizations(settingsInfo.getOrganizations());
            session.setAttribute("currentAnonymous", principal);
        }
    }
    return principal;
}
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/index.htm", params = "method=refreshTestsWithoutSubscriptionClients")
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Object refreshTestsWithoutSubscriptionClients(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam Map<String, Object> pageListParams) {
        TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userInfo = Constants.getCurrentUserInfo(request);
        return familyDao.findTestsWithoutSubscriptionClients(pageListParams, userInfo.getSelectedOrganizationId());
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/index.htm", params = "method=refreshNotPaidLessons")
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Object refreshNotPaidLessons(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam Map<String, Object> pageListParams) {
        TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userInfo = Constants.getCurrentUserInfo(request);
        return familyDao.findNotPaidLessons(pageListParams, userInfo.getSelectedOrganizationId());
    }
```

Ошибку я получаю после того, как перехожу с API-url в обычные разделы программы. То есть она появляется, поскольку система запрашивает логин и права аутентификации для приложения, а получает информацию для API.

Comment: у вас ошибку вызвал [AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver] в методе обработки контролера, и связано ето с   ClassCastException, а не с безопасностью спринга, хотел бы увидеть ваш код в класе контролера

Comment: Дополнила вопрос

Comment: вся суть в том что из HttpServletRequest request вы получаете public java.lang.Object, что не обязательно есть UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken который вы потом кастуете в TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, Object может быть просто строка, которая не является UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, и поетому не может быть закастовано в TRUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, поетому вы получаете  java.lang.ClassCastException, перед кастом поставте проверку instanceof, и только потом кастуйте, иначе, напишите обработку роботы со строкой а не с UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что в программе реализована собственная логика безопасности. В TRUsernamePasswordAuthentication хранился не только принципал, но и другая информация, необходимая для загрузки методов в бэкенде. Естественно после авторизации для API я получала токен, который совершенно не подходил для другой логики безопасности. Выходом стало простое выражение create-session="stateless", что позволило не создавать сессию и разрешить конфликт двух областей